# How to change all url images in blogger with custom url images

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, blogger

how do I replace all the url images in blogger. example bp1.blogspot.com/image.jpg I want to change it to cdn.staticly.io/img/bp1.blogspot.com/image.jpg?format=webp using javascript or jquery

I can't change those pictures one by one ... there are many thanks

Comment: As a visitor or on your server?

Comment: in my template, I'm making a blogger template and I want my template to use a webp image, coincidentally in blogger it doesn't support webp image ... like it or not the power has to outsmart by utilizing the features of staticly.io

Answer (score 1):

Here are some methods, assuming you MUST process your images on the client

Ugly (loads the initial image, then the other image)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("img[src^='https://bp1.blogspot.com']")].forEach(function(img) {
    let src = img.src;
    img.src = "https: //cdn.staticly.io/img/"+ src + "?format=webp";
  })
})
```

```html
<img src="https://bp1.blogspot.com/image1.jpg" /><br/>
<img src="divider.jpg" />
<img src="https://bp1.blogspot.com/image2.jpg" /><br/>
<img src="https://bp1.blogspot.com/image3.jpg" /><br/>
```

Possibly nicer

Loading the content from an html file with images and replaces them before showing

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("imageSnippet.html", function(html) {
    $("#container").html(html);
    [...document.querySelectorAll("#container img[src^='https://bp1.blogspot.com']")]
    .forEach(function(img) {
      let src = img.src;
      img.src = "https: //cdn.staticly.io/img/" + src + "?format=webp";
    })
    $("#container").show();
  })
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: @ mplungjan thanks you are currect. nested if shoul better perfermance like                       if(src ==  'blogger. example bp1.blogspot.com/image.jpg') this.src = “https://cdn.staticly.io/img/“+ src + "?format=webp";
  })

Comment: Please see update. Nesting ifs does not speed things up. I have changed the code to only take images starting with the relevant URL

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```js
$('img').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace(/^(http:|https:)?\/\//,'https://cdn.statically.io/img/') + "?format=webp");
})
```

Without jQuery:

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) { 
  var src = imgs[i].src;
  imgs[i].src = src.replace(/^(http:|https:)?\/\//,'https://cdn.statically.io/img/') + "?format=webp";
}
```

Put the code before the closing body tag `</body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(/.*?:\/\//g , "https://cdn.statically.io/img/") + "?format=webp";
  };
```